# Get pixel RGB value from video - Objective-C Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation, pixel, rgb

I'd like to get a specific pixel's RGB value using an X/Y coordinate from a video file.

Like, go through the video and print the current timecode (+fps) and RGB value of pixel at X/Y coordinate.

Can anyone give me a starting point for this?

I've seen a few examples using AVCaptureSession on iOS that use

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

To convert the sampleBuffer to a CIImage and grab the pixel value from wherever...

Can this same technique be accomplished using a preexisting video file playing back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at using [`AVAssetImageGenerator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetImageGenerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which will allow you to directly generate images from the video in the background.